# How to create oracle dblink to netezza

Tags: netezza

Is there a way how to create a dblink from oracle to netezza in order to insert data in Netezza from Oracle side?

Comment: I want to query data from Netezza in Oracle, low volume however

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC, as IBM provides an ODBC driver for Netezza.

[About Oracle Database Gateways](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/gateways/index.html)

[Configuration for ODBC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31042/configodbc.htm)

I can't speak about performance or the cost of this option, however.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do it

Comment: Note that the typical way that we've done this in the past is to use a tool like FastReader or DBCrane to unload the data from oracle to a named pipe, then have NZLoad running to read from that named pipe. We've moved several terabytes of data this way in < 1 hr (on a 10  gigabit network)

Answer (score 0):

in our project we loaded data from oracle table to flat file in unix flatform  using sqlplus/sqlloader utility and then load the data from flat file to netezza using nzload utility. for this we have used the unix shell script. u can also do the same thing from netezza to oracle using nzsql.